# During assignments, separate entity stores are not being created for each new entity type?

Tags: functions

The documentation for EntityRegister gives this example:

> During assignments, separate entity stores are created for each new entity type:

```
Entity["MyType1", "e"]["p"] = 915;
Entity["MyType2", "f"]["q"] = "abc";  
EntityStores[]
```

And that returns two new EntityStores.

When I run the given assignments, I get two errors. e.g.:

> Set: Tag Entity in Entity[MyType1,e][p] is Protected.

Why the error? I unprotected Entity and ran the assignment again, but that did not have the intended effect.

(MacOS; 12.3.1.0)

Another detail: the assignment works just fine if there exists a registered EntityStore with the specified Type.

Fixed the code to be what it is, rather than expressing irrelevant detail (Ins and Outs) and breaking the syntax.

Comment: I think you syntax is wrong. Have a look in the help at: "workflow/SetUpAnEntityStore"

Comment: The syntax is correct. This is why I specified that the assignment works just fine if there exists a registered EntityStore with the specified type. I can store an association of associations with a "fruit" Type and add extra fruit, and I can copy and paste the specified entities from the post, change their type to "fruit" and add them to the already registered EntityStore. I am not typing [in] or [out] in the code, I am just illustrating what the documentation looks like and says. Perhaps you're right and I should not illustrate that in that way. I'll fix that. But the syntax is correct.

Comment: I think you have first to register the EntityStore for MyType1/2 using `EntityRegister` before using them.

Comment: Documentation for EntityRegister says: "If no EntityStore in EntityStores[] contains "type", a new EntityStore is registered." The example in this post is the example given in the documentation, which portrays functionality that returns an error when I run it. That's the reason for this question.

Comment: Full quote: "During assignments Entity["type","name"][property]=value, data is stored in the first EntityStore in EntityStores[] that contains "type". If no EntityStore in EntityStores[] contains "type", a new EntityStore is registered."